# What can I actually do with a Harmony Hub?

Tags: logitech-harmony

I am considering getting a [Logitech Harmony Hub](https://secure.logitech.com/en-us/product/harmony-hub?crid=60). It's my understanding that I can define activities which can entail using certain commands of the compatible devices. However, I am unable to find what kind of actions I can use within these activities and if these activities can contain several actions for the same device.

Is it possible to automatically switch my TV, my home cinema system and Fire TV on, and set all of them to the proper input modes when they have booted? Is there a list somewhere of the things I can and cannot do with the Harmony Hub?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible to automatically switch my TV, my home cinema system
>   and FireTV on and set all of them to the proper input modes when they
>   booted?

Yes, this is a standard activity. Here are two sample activities:

- **Watch Roku** - Receiver power on, Receiver input set to HDMI1, TV power on, TV input set to HDMI1 (note: no commands to Roku since it is always on)
- **Watch TV** - Receiver power on, Receiver input set to Optical In, TV power on, TV input set to ANT

There is some info here:
[Understanding Harmony Activities](https://support.myharmony.com/en-us/understanding-harmony-activities)

You can also bind different buttons to different commands for different activities.

Comment: So I can basically do everything I could do with the device's remote and I can chain these commands and group them with commands for other devices?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. It's very powerful and makes it so you don't need multiple remotes anymore.